# Getting a stackoverflowexception and don't know why. can anyone help please?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I'm new to this and I'm following the instructions step by step but for some reason keep getting the stackoverflowexception. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace assignment3
{
    class changeValue
    {
        //Create a class called changeValue that declares 2 integer class variables:  value1 and 
        //  value2.  These should be declared as public and you should not use automatic properties 
        // to declare them. 
        public int value1
        {
            get
            {
                return value1;
            }//end get
            set
            {
                value1 = value;
            }//end set
        }
        public int value2
        {
            get
            {
                return value2;
            }//end get
            set
            {
                value2 = value;
            }//end set
        }

    public changeValue(int val1, int val2)
    {
        //here is the constructor where you code the if statements
        int value1 = val1;
        int value2 = val2;

        if (value1 > 5)
        { 
            value1 = val1; 
        }
        if (val1 <= 5)
        {
            value1 = (val1+val2);
        }
        if (val2 < 10)
        {
            value2 = (val2 * val2 + 5);
        }
        if (val2 >= 10)
        {
            value2 = val2;
        }
    }

    public void printit()
    {
        //here is the printit method used to print the results
       Console.WriteLine("The calculated value is:" + (value1 * value2));

    }
}
class assignment3
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declare the local val1 and val2 integer variables
        int val1;
        int val2;    

        //prompt the user for input of two integers
        //don’t forget to convert from the string input to integer
        Console.Write("Enter an integer value: "); //obtain user input
        val1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter a second integer value: "); //obtain user input
        val2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //instantiate a changeValue object here
        changeValue myValue = new changeValue(val1,val2);

        myValue.printit();//call the object method printit here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The getter for `value1` returns `value1` ,which calls the getter for `value1`, which returns `value1` which calls the getter for `value1` which...

Comment: Six answers in less than three minutes... wow.

Comment: whats the record for most answers in 10 minutes.

Comment: @eddie_cat There are a lot of home runs in softball...

Comment: StackOverflow people have some inclination towards this particular exception, so answers come in quickly. :)

Comment: You should also follow [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx), so PascalCase properties.

Comment: @DStanley my thoughts exactly, lol.

Comment: @DStanley Howver, in basesball, soccer, and softball, all points count as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your creating what is essentially a circular reference. Your getter and setter need backer fields.

```
private int _value1;
private int _value2;

public int Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return _value1;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            _value1= value;
        }//end set
    }
    public int Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return _value2;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            _value2 = value;
        }//end set
    }
```

The way you have it , by setting the value1 = value, you have created an infinite loop.

Comment: ok..now I'm understanding it better, why can't the damn textbook explain things better? lol.

Comment: I think if you have a textbook, you overlooked certain things. Maybe it used a capital V and a lower can V. I don't think the exact code you posted would be in a textbook. If it is, I would find a different book to teach me coding.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. But now when it calculates, the calculated values is always coming back as 0.

Comment: thats a totally different problem, but what did you type into it?

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion..could the problem be this?

Comment: //instantiate a changeValue object here
        changeValue myValue = new changeValue(val1,val2);

Comment: it depends on what you changed, if you changed value1 to Value1 in the property, but not in the parameters or main[], then yes it could cause a problem.

Answer (score 4):

These are your problems, they are self referencing.

```
    public int value1
    {
        get
        {
            return value1;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            value1 = value;
        }//end set
    }
    public int value2
    {
        get
        {
            return value2;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            value2 = value;
        }//end set
    }
```

Change them to:

```
    public int value1 { get; set; }
    public int value2 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The getter for `value1` is calling itself, which recurses infinitely until the call stack is full.

The way to not use automatic properties (which is what you are assigned based on the code comments) is to use a *separate* backing field:

```
    private int _value1;

    public int value1
    {
        get
        {
            return _value1;
        }//end get
        set
        {
            _value1 = value;
        }//end set
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your properties in `changeValue` will cause a `StackOverflowException`:

```
public int value1
{
    get
    {
        return value1;  // --> this line is referencing the property itself and will StackOverflow!
    }//end get
    set
    {
        value1 = value;
    }//end set
}
```

Instead, try using a simple auto-property:

```
public int value1 { get; set; }
```

Or use a backing store with a different name to your property (note the underscore):

```
private int _value1;
public int value1
{
    get
    {
        return _value1;
    }//end get
    set
    {
        _value1 = value;
    }//end set
}
```